# Symfony event subscriber doesn't react to dispatch

Tags: php, symfony, events, listener

I'm using a service with an autowired dispatcher to dispatch an event. In order to test events, I've added an event subscriber just before dispatching the event. However, the registered subscriber isn't logging the method I would expect it to do.

The event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class GameStartEvent extends Event {

}
```

The subscriber:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareTrait;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class GameStartSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    use LoggerAwareTrait;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->setLogger($logger);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            "game.started" => [
                [
                    'logEvent',
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function logEvent(GameStartEvent $event): void {
        $this->logger->info("the game has started");
    }
}
```

And this is the used service that is supposed to dispatch events the event registration is supposed to happen somewhere else in the future. I just did it here for testing:

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Event\GameStartEvent;
use App\Event\GameStartSubscriber;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class GameCacheService {

    private $eventDispatcher;

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    // some other methods...

    function startGame() {
        // some code...

        $gameStartSubscriber = new GameStartSubscriber($this->logger);
        $this->eventDispatcher->addSubscriber($gameStartSubscriber);

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch("game.started", new GameStartEvent());   
    }
}
```

After calling the service method, the specified logger message isn't written down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Replace 

`$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch("game.started", new GameStartEvent());`

with

`$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch("game.started", $event);`</del>

You seem to have at least your Event in `App/Entity` which is not autowired by default and shouldn't be. Have a look at your services.yml, it should be excluded from Autowiring. Move your stuff to something like `App/Event`

Comment: There is no `$event` variable present in the service method. Also I'm pretty sure the variable is not the problem. If that were the case, I would probably get some kind of exception stating that I didn't provide a proper parameter for the `logEvent` method.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, this answer is total crap. I tested your code and it works for me. Do you know if it's the dispatcher, the event or the logger that's not working? Also you seem to have the Event namespace `App\Entity`. You sure that's correct?